# Does elasticsearch consider empty string as null?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I would like to know if elasticsearch considers empty string as null value, but based on my mapping shown below, I don't see that it is doing that. How can I make elasticsearch consider empty string as a `null` and index using the value provided by `null_value`. My mapping is shown below:

```
{
    "mapping": {
        "my_typee": {
            "properties": {
                "autoRank": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "null_value": 0,
                    "store": true,
                    "index": "analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not index empty strings. In your case your field is actually not string but an integer of type. And `null_value` option is actually does what you want to do. You dont need to do anything extra.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html